# Why Spring Preloader shouldn't be installed on the production environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, backend, production-environment

I was reading through some of the articles on what spring is and why there is a need of application preloader, although it speeds up your development and can be a good usage on your development environment.

The thing that I want to understand is, why Spring Pre-loader should not be installed on production environment?

This is related specifically for Ruby on Rails Applications.

I don't find any relevant answers for this on google.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the history on that `README.md`. Here's the [original description](https://github.com/rails/spring/commit/e7adf31c4b835a8cbedc33c737c2bf64e2b03d7d).

> You must not install Spring on production environment to prevent it from running there by providing --without development test argument to the bundle install command which is used to install gems on your production machines:

It seems to have originated from [this issue](https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/318) regarding spring being started when `bundle exec rails console production` was executed. The reason it's blocked is to not surprise users using `rails console`. More details are available on that original issue